# Several objects at same position - how to decide which is rendered

Tags: three.js

I have the situation that I may have multiple objects at the same location and I want to be able to choose which one gets rendered in terms of color etc. Is there any such way? I cannot use csg since those operations are too time consuming for my case

Cheers
Tom

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide it yourself and hide all of them but the one you want to show.

Comment: Not sure I get you right. The objects are partially overlapping. Thus I cannot just use `scene.remove(mesh)` if that's what you mean. Or do you mean another way of hiding the relevant parts? Best thing I came up with so far is sightly increasing the size in the relevant direction so that one is definitely in front even if it's just for 0.000001 units.

Comment: @Tom hide/show is not the same thing as add/remove from scene. You have to hide the object (it means traverse all its childs and hide them... like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122919/how-to-hide-show-objects-using-three-js-release-54#14123978 even the example is for the release 54 should work pretty much in the same way). Scaling is another option, but from my point of view, if you don't want to see it, you hide it, as less shown objects in the scene/view, less GPU overhead ;)